# Posts - users use html markup instead of regular

Tags: discussion, markdown

I just edited a post on Worldbuilding SE:

https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/16647

I kind of understand users' temptation to use `<pre></pre>` for tabular data and/or code(don't have to indent each line, right?) but I don't understand why someone would want to use regular HTML over SE markup for links etc.

In a [comment](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/15062/stumped-how-can-i-get-a-huge-earth-like-planet/15076#comment39732_15076) below the same post, is has led to the `<a>` showing and also half-link, half text, so a disaster. One user was even trying to post a link and expecting it to automatically convert to image or something.

I have seen posts specifically attributed to code markups, but not a generalized discussion on this.

Should we allow or disallow this practice of using HTML instead of SE markup?

Comment: Some people are just used to write in a certain way. I also only use `[foo](http://www.example.com)` and not using the Hyperlink editor icon, just because it became a habit. I don't think it should be disallowed, just maybe explain to people how to do it properly when it breaks things.

Comment: I use the two square brackets. That's the post syntax for links, right? Maybe we should put a notification on the post edit page to discourage it, simply because it's not in the design, just a side effect(since the page is getting rendered in HTML). Not to mention the possibility of the habit leading to a Java template `Map<Project,List<Employee>>` getting rendered simply as Map>.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thanks for the other one. Yes, my question is essentially identical to that one. Maybe it didn't show up because I used 'markup' in search. Not a very common word in here, it seems.

Comment: Cheers, it wasn't easy to find, had to just go over questions tagged [tag:discussion] and [tag:markdown]. As for the two square brackets you're right, it's an alias to what I'm using, and still counts as markdown. Not really relevant since neither of those is HTML. :)